# gettng Cannot reiniatilize DataTable when using jquery dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have got an array of symbols , when processing each of the element in the array , I am storing the present Milliseconds , Seconds , Minutes and that array element , storing all those in an array .

Once  all the elements in the array are processed , i am  building a table with that array data using Jquery DataTables .

And i am contining this process after every 4 seconds , expecting that the table will be refreshed after every 4 seconds

But i am observing that the Symbol is not being shown and table is also not being refeshed .

I am getting an error alert stating that Cannot reinitialize Data table

Could anybody plese help me ??

This is my complete programm

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
        </script>
        <script>
        var myarray = [];
var myJSON = "";
var symbols = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];

function buildArray(value) {

    var date = new Date();
    var Milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var value = this.value;
    var item = {
        "Symbol": value,
        "Milliseconds": Milliseconds,
        "seconds": seconds,
        "minutes": minutes,
    };
    myarray.push(item);


}

function createTable() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "aaData": myarray,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "Symbol",

            "data": "Milliseconds"
        }, {
            "data": "seconds"
        }, {
            "data": "minutes"
        }

        ]
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    doPoll();
});

function doPoll() {
    $.each(symbols, function(index, value) {
        buildArray(value);
    });
    createTable();
    myarray = [] ;
    setTimeout(doPoll, 4000);
}
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                        Symbol
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Milliseconds
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Seconds
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Minutes
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to destroy the datatable before recreating in your `doPoll()` function

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
createTable();
```